# how to get reference of JavaScript module being loaded using script tag dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My usecase is to mount and unmount react component into container div dynamically , in same container different components will be mounted in different times dynamically.in this context i am using external script to load that module from CDN, once loaded i should be able to get reference of the module being loaded ( for example App in "import App from './App')

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.setAttribute('id', 'test');
scr.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scr.setAttribute('src', 'https://test.com/abc.js');
scr.onload = () => {
    // Here i want to get the reference of abc.js i.e exported module in abc.js is ABC , i want to get ABC programmatically 

      // I know ABC is loaded but I don't want to hard code it.


    }
   body.appendChild(scr);
```

Please help me how to get reference of module being loaded in onLoad callback function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The thing that is exported from the module you loaded will be added to the global scope, so you just reference the exported variable.  In the example provided, you can just start using `ABC`.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to hard code `ABC`?  You'd rather assign `ABC` to another variable and reference it?  I'm not sure that's any better.  Unless you want to use something like `webpack` or `browserify`, the exported module is globally accessible.

Comment: _"In same container different components will be mounted in different times dynamically."_ OP doesn't want to write `ABC` because the imported component might not be `ABC`.

Comment: @user7175350 If you create a variable in your component files that all have the same name (e.g., `component`), you can import them and then use `component` in your HTML script to reference whatever component was loaded.

Comment: @Adam,thank you , that is my fall back approach, having same component name in all modules so that we can use Component , i am not sure how it works again if we have multiple modules with same component name in memory ( loaded in different times i mean) ?

Comment: @c1moore thank you for responding, what i mean is once abc.js is loaded into global scope i want to access it like {modulename}.test , here modulename will change, If I write ABC.test it will be always ABC no matter what module i load ..

Comment: @c1moore you are right we can access this way let moduleName = 'Module1';
      let lib = window[moduleName]; it is there in window object thank you so much you are rocks..